# Как облегчить кусок кода php?

Tags: php

Как облегчить этот "костыль" в функцию ?

```
 if ($this->mother_lpr) {
        $parent_surname = $this->mother_surname;
        $parent_name = $this->mother_name;
        $parent_middle_name = $this->mother_middle_name;
        $parent_phone = $this->mother_phone;
        $parent_viber = $this->mother_viber;
        $parent_email = $this->mother_email;
        $parent_facebook = $this->mother_facebook;
        $parent_instagram = $this->mother_instagram;
    }elseif($this->father_lpr){
        $parent_surname = $this->father_surname;
        $parent_name = $this->father_name;
        $parent_middle_name = $this->father_middle_name;
        $parent_phone = $this->father_phone;
        $parent_vider = $this->father_vider;
        $parent_email = $this->father_email;
        $parent_facebook = $this->father_facebook;
        $parent_instagram = $this->father_instagram;
    }elseif($this->other_relative_lpr){
        $parent_surname = $this->other_relative_surname;
        $parent_name = $this->other_relative_name;
        $parent_middle_name = $this->other_relative_middle_name;
        $parent_phone = $this->other_relative_phone;
        $parent_viber = $this->other_relative_viber;
        $parent_email = $this->other_relative_email;
        $parent_facebook = $this->other_relative_facebook;
        $parent_instagram = $this->other_relative_instagram;
    }
```

Comment: А можно хранить каждого родственника отдельным объектом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код писал по памяти. Если будут ошибки, напишите в комментарии.

```
$result = [];
$attributes = ['surname', 'middle_name', 'name', 'phone'];

$base = null;
if ($this->mother_lpr) {
    $base = 'mother_';
} elseif ($this->father_lpr) {
    $base = 'father_';
} elseif ($this->other_relative_lpr) {
    $base = 'other_relative_';
}

if ($base) {
   foreach ($attributes as $a) {
       $result['parent_' . $a] = $this->{$base . $a};
   }
}

extract($result);
```

Comment: На выходе получился пустой массив

Comment: Код обновил. Фигурная скобка одно отсутствовала. Код рабочий